# VB click button on Website

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I'm using the following code to navigate to a web site and then predetermine the drop downs on the page and it works fine...

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
  Dim IE As Object
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Navigate "https://postimage.io/"
  IE.Visible = True
  While IE.busy
    DoEvents
  Wend
  IE.document.All("optsize").Value = "8"
  IE.document.All("expire").Value = "0"
End Sub
```

... however there is a button on the page *Choose images* i would like my script to click  that and in the pop-up enter a address of an image then press *open*

is this possible? if so could someone please help me achieve it

Comment: Are you talking about an address on the file system or a web address?

Comment: It is a button on the website  https://postimage.io